# Merging master into dev/branch will overwrite dev/branch

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I am attempting to merge master into my dev/branch, which has a new component X. Once the merge is complete, this component X from dev/branch is removed since it never existed in master.

The only merge conflicts I get seem to be from unrelated files that I never touched during the programming of component X.

What is going on here and how can I fix this and merge in the proper way?

Comment: Merging master to dev shouldn't wipe out brand new changes. Anything that's **new** on dev would stay, anything that's **new** on master will also stay. You'd be getting merge conflicts if something that **exists** was changed in both places. That's how merging works. Either you're resolving the merge conflicts incorrectly, or there is something very wrong in the history.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from this which of your characterizations is simply wrong, because you provide none of the evidence you're looking at and only offer your conclusions about it, but that's not the only thing wrong here. Whatever "component" is actually supposed to refer to, your description simply doesn't match anything about how merging behaves.  Show the actual evidence you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to merge master in dev/branch. Shouldn't you merge dev/branch into master?
Also, your hypothesis is incorrect.

> Once the merge is complete, this component X from dev/branch is removed since it never existed in master.

When you merge master to your dev branch. All the commits that are on master and not on you dev/branch will be added to your `dev/branch`. And in your case the same is happening. And the unrelated code you are saying is actually on master which will be merged to `dev/branch` and git probably doesn't know which branch's code it uses to create a merge landing you to the conflict.

I suggest, that you abort the merge using `git merge --abort` and spend some time to think that do you really want to merge master to dev/branch? What exactly you want to achieve.